# how to tokenize list values n number of times

Tags: java

```
   public void readTemplateInput() {
        BufferedReader inputfile = null;       
        try {
            File file = new File("D:\\inputparam.txt");
            inputfile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String line = inputfile.readLine(); 
            if(line!=null){
            StringTokenizer reporttokens = new StringTokenizer(line,"-");
            while (reporttokens.hasMoreTokens()) {                
                 String tokens= reporttokens.nextToken().toString();  
                 reportslist=new ArrayList();
                 reportslist.add(tokens);
                 getReportTokens(reportslist);
              }           
            }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(InputTemplateData.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(InputTemplateData.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }    
        finally {
            try {
                inputfile.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(InputTemplateData.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

    public void getReportTokens(List reportslist) {
        List reports=reportslist;

}
```

here i need to get the first list and need to assign that list to a string and need tokenization.This procedure repeats like list2 assigned to a string and tokenizing it ,and list3...... so on according to the .txt file.
    I dont have idea to resolve this.
    Will any body help with correct code.

Comment: You are reading the file line-by-line, where you try to tokenize the line with the delimiter "-", but reading your file line-by-line actually separate the lines which makes the delimiter "-" useless in this case

Comment: will u give me some code regarding this.will u add some code so that i will follow

Comment: one more note, StringTokenizer is a legacy class .. use .split() function instead directly on a String

Comment: will u add some code so that i will follow

Answer (score 1):

Here's your code modified to use `split()` instead, except I have no idea how is your data actually formatted, and how should it be parsed .. the code will split all lines along with all delimiters I can see in your example in one final list ..

```
public ArrayList<String> readTemplateInput()
{

    BufferedReader inputfile = null;
    ArrayList<String> finalList = null;

    try
    {
        File file = new File("D:\\inputparam.txt");
        inputfile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line = inputfile.readLine();

            finalList = new ArrayList<String> ();

        if(line!=null)
        {
            String[] listA = line.split("-");

            ArrayList<String> listB = new ArrayList<String>();

            for (String str : listA)
            {
                listB.addAll(str.split("#").asList());
            }

            ArrayList<String> listC = new ArrayList<String>();

            for (String str : listB)
            {
                listC.addAll(str.split("$").asList());
            }

            ArrayList<String> listD = new ArrayList<String>();

            for (String str : listC)
            {
                listD.addAll(str.split("\(|\)").asList());
            }

            ArrayList<String> listE = new ArrayList<String>();

            for (String str : listD)
            {
                listE.addAll(str.split(",").asList());
            }

            // filter

            for (String str : listE)
            {
                str.replaceAll("\s+"," ");

            }

            for (int i=0; i<listE.size(); i++)
            {
                if(listE.get(i).equals(" ") || listE.get(i).equals(""))
                {
                    listE.remove(i);
                    i--;
                }
            }

                    finalList.addAll(listE);
        }

    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
    {
        Logger.getLogger(InputTemplateData.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        Logger.getLogger(InputTemplateData.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            inputfile.close();
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(InputTemplateData.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

            return finalList;
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.the parsing procedure is as follows.first is separate the strings by - then the new string separated by $,then new string separated by # or , will u help on this